# datatables laravel returned html element as a text

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, yajra-datatable

**Please find an [attached pictures][1], the Laravel datatables are returning an html as text.  I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cb8Ev.png**) `rawColumns` and `escapeColumns` but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You code is for server side DataTable setup and execution and now you need to handle it at your client side using [JQuery Ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "type": "POST"
  }
} );
```

If you are newbie, first go through example:

- [How to integrate Datatable in Laravel 5 or Later](https://www.addwebsolution.com/blog/how-integrate-datatable-laravel-5-or-later)
- [Laravel 5.1 with Datatables Quick Starter](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter)

Comment: I settled a client side, but the problem in server side, because it returning HTML element as text